# How to embed if in an echo and returning an <iframe>?

Tags: php, if-statement, iframe, echo

I am trying to use if in an echo with the ternary operator, but instead of a value, when if turns true it should display an iframe

> echo(...'.((!$artArr[$count]["Longitude"] == null &&
> !$artArr[$count]["Latitude"] == null)?<iframe width="425" height="350"
> frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"
> src="https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox='.$artArr[$count]["Longitude"].'%2C'.$artArr[$count]["Latitude"].'%2C'.$artArr[$count]["Longitude"].'%2C'.$artArr[$count]["Latitude"].'&layer=mapnik&marker='.$artArr[$count]["Latitude"].'%2C'.$artArr[$count]["Longitude"].'"
> style="border: 1px solid black">:.')

Comment: This looks very hard to read. I would suggest using an if/else instead of a ternary to break up the line and make it much easier to read now and in the future.

Comment: But if cannot be used in an echo. The echo is much bigger then the snippet i posted here, so i cannot just make another echo in between to include the if statement

Comment: Break up the echos. You can use multiple echo statements, you don't need to shove it all into one. Or create a string variable with the if/else and then echo that out.

Comment: Ok thx i will try it this way.